# How In Azure Devops To Not Apply Pre Deployment Approval When Approver Self Request Deployment?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**ANSWER:**

In Azure Devops we have created a policy for pre deployment approval when deploying a new version of master to `Test` and `Production`.

**QUESTION:**

We have only one approver and do not want this pre deployment approval to kick in when the approver himself requests a deployment, but only when other users request a deployment.

Is it possible to achieve that in Azure Devops?

Comment: hi, how the thing going? Does the below answer can fix your error? If yes, you can accept the answer, it will help other community user who get the same error. If not, you can free to leave your comment here or could you please provide the above information? : )

Answer (score 1):

You can check this option.
[image]

And when the only approver himself requests a deployment, he should reassign a new approver to deploy the follow stages.
[image]

Hope this helps.